# No puedo conectar la base de datos MYSQL Visual Studio 2019

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] me sala ese error al agregar la base de datos pongo todo bien, me dice conexión exitosa, pero cuando doy click en database name me salta lo que dice la imagen

Comment: que versión de MySQL tienes?

Comment: 8.0.31 esa versión tengo . Mysql 8.0 CE

Comment: Instala la versión 5.7.22, luego descarga MySQL.Data y MySQL de nuGet y ya luego conectas con visual studio